# How to change the format of a list of books/authors with regex?

Tags: regex

I have a list of books/authors in this format:

```
1. Suttree by Cormac McCarthy
2. Summersault by April Willis
3. Autumn's Ghost by Brian Johnson
```

And what I need is to transform it into this format:

```
Cormac McCarthy - Suttree
April Willis - Summersault
Brian Johnson - Autumn's Ghost
```

How could I do this with regex?

Comment: What language are you working on? This can be done more efficiently without regexps.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `/^\d+\. (.*) by (.*)$/` with `$2 - $1`.

Note that book titles can contain the word "by", and in theory so can an author's name. So in some cases there may be more than one way to parse the result and it might not be clear which is the correct interpretation. You may want to search the list of books for lines where the word "by" occurs more than once and verify manually that they have been parsed correctly.

Comment: Luckily, author's names are, at least, unlikely to contain "by", so this solution (pretty much the same one I gave), which matches the book greedily, is most likely to give the right answer.

Comment: Titles are probably a lot more likely to contain "by" as a word than authors' names are, so it's probably safest to split on the *last* " by " -- which incidentally your code already does by way of matching the title greedily.

Answer (score 0):

Match the regex `^\d+\.[ \t]+(.+)[ \t]+by[ \t]+(.+)$`, and replace every occurrence of it with `$2 - $1` or `\2 - \1`, depending on your regex engine.  The regex works like this:

1. `^`: Match at the start of a line.
2. `\d+\.`: First, match one or more digits followed by a literal `.`.
3. `[ \t]+`: Match one or more spaces or tabs.
4. `(.+)`: Match as much as you can (the book), and save it as the first capturing group.
5. `[ \t]+by[ \t]+`: Match the string `by`, surrounded one or more spaces or tabs.
6. `(.+)`: Match as much as you can (the author), and save it as the first capturing group.
7. `$`: Match the end of a line.

Comment: More convenient than `[ \t]`, and somewhat easier to read lest the space be lost, is the `\h` charclass escape that Perl-derived regex engines recognize. It stands for any character with the “horizontal whitespace” property. The most common are SPACE, TAB, and NO-BREAK SPACE, but it also includes things like FIGURE SPACE, THIN SPACE, HAIR SPACE, and NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE. The exact list of hex code points matched by `\h` is: 9, 20, A0, 1680, 180E, 2000-200A, 202F, 205F, and 3000.

Comment: @tchrist: Very nice, I've not seen that before.  I imagine that's less widely supported, though?  (This is why one wants to know what language people are using with their regexes!)  I'll switch over to it where I can, though.